# Possible to access java variable in ApplicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, variables, object

We're using the Springframework. Is it possible to access an existing variable from a java class in ApplicationContext.xml?

For instance, we have a class with a threadnumber which is initialized on 5. Is there a way to read that '5' in the applicationcontext, so we can use it to inject other Java classes?

If yes, how?

Kind regards,

Walle

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring 3, you should be able to do it using Spring EL. Check out http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Here is an example assuming you want to use a public static field THREAD_NUMBER of class mypackage.MyClass:

```
  <bean id="myBean"
        class="mypackage.AnotherClass">
    <property name="theProperty">
      <value>#{T(mypackage.MyClass).THREAD_NUMBER}</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

If it's not a static field but an instance field you would need a bean first and then call an apropriate getter from Spring EL expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use EL or using an older version of Spring,

```
<bean id="myBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticField" value="MyClass.MY_STATIC_FIELD"/> </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `BeanPostProcessor`. It could probably do what you want.